# grails 3.0 facebook plugin spring social facebook using default appId 962223610477458

Tags: facebook-graph-api, grails, grails-3.0, spring-social-facebook

I'm using the

- http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/index.html
- java version "1.8.0_91"
- Grails Version: 3.0.9 & Groovy Version: 2.4.5

I'm not sure where is is being inserted at. I've added the appid to application.yml, application.groovy, src\main\resources\application.properties.

````
DEBUG com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.SpringSecurityFacebookGrailsPlugin - Facebook security config: [appId
:********, secret:********, apiKey:Invalid, domain:[classname:com.spontorg.FacebookUser, appUserConnectionPropertyName:u
ser], useAjax:true, autoCheck:true, jsconf:fbSecurity, permissions:[email, user_friends, public_profile], taglib:[langua
ge:en_US, button:[text:Login with Facebook], initfb:true], autoCreate:[enabled:true, roles:[ROLE_USER, ROLE_FACEBOOK]],
filter:[json:[processUrl:/j_spring_security_facebook_json, type:json, methods:[POST]], redirect:[redirectFromUrl:/j_spri
ng_security_facebook_redirect], processUrl:/j_spring_security_facebook_check, type:redirect, position:720, forceLoginPar
ameter:j_spring_facebook_force], beans:[:], host:localhost]

....

DEBUG com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthUtils - Redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8080/j_spring_securi
ty_facebook_check
`````

afterwards the URL redirect is

````
Location:https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=962223610477458&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fj_spring_security_facebook_check&scope=email%2Cuser_friends%2Cpublic_profile&state=0-c68ca

````

then i get an error 72, and some message about the app is setup for public access, etc.

Answer (score 0):

WELP... 
It was me, i must have copy/pasted that in and never looked closely enough. IDK?

I checked the source code & it was pretty clearly pulling that value, rechecked and DOH! 
finally got it, you need to match the host: with the value you put in ont the facebook app or it pukes again with a different error.

`grails:
    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            facebook:
                appId: '###########'
                secret: 'asfd!@#$asfdasfd!#'
                domain:
                     classname: 'com.domain.FacebookUser'
                host: live.yourdomain.com
                filter:
                    type: redirect
                permissions: ['email','user_friends','public_profile']`